# Using Eclipse with AVRDude

Tags: eclipse, arduino, atmel, avrdude

I am trying to program my Arduino through Eclipse (because Eclipse is the easiest IDE for beginners), but apparently, when I go to update my programmer in Eclipse for AVRDude, it shows that the configuration file is not found. Additionally, it also says that it doesn't support any of the MCU's I'm trying to communicate with... even weirder. Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would politely disagree with the statement that Eclipse is easiest for beginners. It's a fantastic IDE for experienced programmers, but getting started with Eclipse any language/dev environment is always problematic for someone learning a particular environment.

So I suggest that the fix to learning how to configure an Arduino development environment is to use the [official Arduinio IDE](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/Software) designed for beginners (and experienced users). It will get you running almost immediately out of the box on any platform.

Answer (score -2):

Trouble with Eclipse is daily business:).
After adding -C /etc/avrdude.conf in the AVRdude configuration tab the MCUs are available.